# Problem adding an image to the splash screen in the pub spec folder

Tags: android-studio, flutter, intellij-idea

Whenever I try to add an image to the splash screen (in the pubspec.yaml file) it says that the image property isn't valid, and
When I try to run pub get it says `Because (project name) depends on flutter_native_splash from unknown source "image", version solving failed.`

Regarding that I did add the image to the assets.

[this is a photo of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQviQ.png)

Comment: Have you added `flutter_native_splash` as a dev_dependency and definitely remembered to run `flutter pub get` ?

Comment: The problem is it won't allow me to add both `flutter_native_splash: ^version` and `flutter_native_splash: assets/images/image.png`, it gives me an error if I added both lines in the dev_dependancy.
should I add one of them in other place ?
@DrSatan1

Comment: Still an issue, experiencing allot of difficulty with this for some reason